# Arduino motor shield not compatible with nodemcu

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

Hi to all first of All my english is not good I brought Arduino motor shield  and n..d. E.p 8266 but the connect pin are not compatible how i will connect to node i want to make robo car

Comment: Hard to say. There are at least two issues: mapping the Arduino shield pins to the 8266, and whether or not the shield library would work as-is on the 8266. You might be better off with a generic motor driver board.

Comment: Please provide a link to the motor shield.